# Find and replace Any digit followed by tab followed by any digit, keeping both digits just replacing the tab character

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, notepad++

Using notepad++ or microsoft word:
I need to find a digit followed by "tab" and followed by another digit, just replace the tab by EOL.
example:
$5,974.89 \t 776

Comment: What software are you using? What do you mean "replace by 'enter?'" In your example, is this the before or after example - please provide both using `\t` to represent a tab character.

Comment: emm.. What is EOL?

Answer (score 2):

Using notepad++ (using regex):

find: `(.*[0-9])(\t)([0-9].*)`

replace (by inserting "enter"): `\1\n\3`

[image: notepad++ image]

Comment: @Rohit Gupta, how did you get the image to load? I uploaded the image in FireFox but couldn't get it to load the image - only to display the link.

Comment: You can see the edit history by looking at the edit queue. Use the link e.g. `edited X hours ago` and `Side-by-side Markdown` button. The exclamation mark was missing.

Comment: The two `.*` are useless as well as the capture group for `\t`; a more efficient regex: `(\d)\t(\d)` and replace: `$1\n$2`